# Get checked checkboxes in PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

I can't get the input of checkboxes in PHP.
Here is my code:

```
echo "<table>";

while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array( $ergebnis, MYSQLI_ASSOC )){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' id='".$zeile['AGName']."'/> </td>";
    echo "<td>". $zeile['AGName'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

#this is the part that probably isn't correct.
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
    $checked_count = count($_POST['check_list']);
    echo "You have selected following ".$checked_count." option(s): <br/>";
}
```

I would like to get the amount of checkboxes checked.
The checkboxes are created in a loop with the input of a database.
Even if this would work, how would I get the id of all of the checked checkboxes?

Comment: Do you actually have a _form_ that you are submitting?

Comment: you can't get the ID, that's client-side only. But if you give your checkbox a _value_, then you can get that back.  See this link: https://makitweb.com/get-checked-checkboxes-value-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not using the `form` to submit. Place your table inside the `form`

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
  echo "<table>";

  while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array( $ergebnis, MYSQLI_ASSOC )){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='".$zeile['AGName']."'/> </td>";
    echo "<td>". $zeile['AGName'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
 }

 echo "</table>";

?>
</form>
```

You can get the `post` values

```
if($_POST){
   $checked_count = count($_POST['check_list']);
   echo "You have selected following ".$checked_count." option(s): <br/>";
 }
```

Simple form with checkboxes:-

```
<form name="" action="" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="gender[]" value="Male" />Male
  <input type="checkbox" name="gender[]" value="Female" />Female
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The PHP code to get the selected:-=

```
if(isset($_POST['gender'])){
   $options = $_POST['gender'];
   echo implode(',', $options);
}
```

If you want to pass the id you can do it like

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="gender[2]" value="Male" />Male
 <input type="checkbox" name="gender[3]" value="Female" />Female
```

You can loop through each option

```
foreach($options as $key => $value){
   echo $key.'---'.$value;
}
//$key is the id sepcified, $values is the seected value
```

Comment: this doesn't answer "how would I get the id of all of the checked checkboxes" at the end of the question

Comment: you still haven't shown how to actually retrieve each value in the PHP...

Comment: how to actually retrieve each value in the PHP. OP wants to know how they would actually get those submitted values in the PHP code and use them. You've shown how to _submit_ them, but not how to _use_ them

Comment: print_r($_POST['check_list'])

Comment: For crude debugging purposes, yes. But that will print out extraneous info like the array structure. And doesn't allow each value to be used separately. How about a foreach loop? `foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $value) echo $value;` I would think (as a really basic example)

Comment: read the question carefully, he want to count the selected checkboxes , he don't want to loop through them

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, I already have a form with a submit, it still doesn't work. I just thought I'd try to post a little less code.

Comment: @RakeshJakhar nope...see the last bit " how would I get the **id** of all of the checked checkboxes". As you can see, the ID contains a specific value. So he wants to know each of those values. He already asked for the count earlier in the question. Come on, you've answered the first part of that by altering the HTML, and I've answered the second part of it for you in my last comment. All you have to do is add it to your answer and you'll get an upvote. I'm trying to _help_ you and instead you're arguing with me...